# How do you remove the "New My Webex Integration" button from Outlook?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook-2013, webex

I installed Webex to attend one meeting and then uninstalled it. Now there's a "New My Webex Integration" button remaining in my Outlook calendar view.  How do you remove this left-over?

I'm running Windows 8.1 with Outlook 2013.  All Webex items have been uninstalled from "Add/Remove Programs". There are no Webex Outlook add-ins.  The seemingly corresponding menu item is grayed out and not removable when you try to hide it using the ribbon editor.

Thanks.

Comment: Start with running Outlook in safe mode. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when opening Outlook, is it still there? It might be worth it to check add-ins and the ribbon editor at that point.

Comment: Resetting ribbon customisations should make [the button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iGgnF.png) go away.

Comment: Michael, I didn't know about safe mode.  Good suggestion; however when in safe mode the button is still there, no add-in visible, and the ribbon editor doesn't work.

Comment: Karen, unfortunately resetting ribbon customisations also leaves the button there.  Maybe Webex installed something via the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps below to remove the My WebEx Integration Title:

1. Open Microsoft Outlook.
2. Bring up the calendar view.
3. Right-click on the "Calendar" item in the tree (My Calendars -> Calendar).  Select Properties from the context menu.
4. Click on the General tab.
5. In the drop-down menu next to "When posting for this folder, use", select IPM.Appointment.
6. Click OK to save the changes.
7. Close and re-open Outlook.